# Rewrite folders with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For a website, I want to set up a redirection using .htaccess.
My folder structure is something like

```
/
/folderA/
/folderB/
/index/
```

where folderA and B and index contain subfolders and files. Now, I want to rewrite all requests for the root `/` and for all not existing folders and files to `index`. It should be masked. It seems to me like an easy task but I cannot get it to work. So far, I tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /index/$1 [L]
```

The redirection somehow works but it does not work when I call the root  *http://example.org/* directly.
Is the root also seen as valid directory or excluded in the RewriteCond checks? Any ideas how to realize that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the root is also a directory. You will need to add another rule to rewrite the root only. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /index/ [L]
```

And since the root is a directory, you might as well exclude this from the first rule. ie. Change `(.*)` to `(.+)`.

HOWEVER, your existing rule will result in a rewrite-loop (500 error) if the URL you are rewriting to in `/index/...` does not exist either<sup>***1**</sup>. eg. If you request `/foo`, it rewrites to `/index/foo` and if `/index/foo` does not exist then it rewrites to `/index/index/foo` to `/index/index/index/foo` etc.

You will need to add an additional condition (or use a negative lookahead) to prevent requests to `/index/...` itself being rewritten.

<sup>(***1** Unless you have another `.htaccess` file in the `/index` subdirectory that contains mod_rewrite directives and you have not enabled mod_rewrite inheritance.)</sup>

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+) /index/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^$ /index/ [L]
```

Comment: This does not only solve the problem, it is also a perfect explanation about what's going on. Thank you very much!